# Rails gem Reform отображение ошибок

Tags: ruby-on-rails, форма

Помогите разобраться как выводить ошибки валидации формы, используя [gem Reform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghGPt.png). Ничего другого, кроме как использовать `notice` в качестве вывода ошибок валидации придумать не смог.

Проблема в том, что если форма не проходит валидацию - не сохраняется текущее состояние формы(пример на картинке). То есть, если форма содержит 20 полей и пользователь ошибся в одном - ему прийдется перезаполнять форму заново. А это не правильно.

В документации ничего по данному вопросу отыскать не смог.

[image: пример классического вывода ошибок валидации]

**Form-object:**

```
class AddressForm < Reform::Form
  include Reform::Form::ActiveModel
  include Reform::Form::ActiveModel::FormBuilderMethods

  model :address

  property :first_name
  property :last_name
  property :address
  property :city
  property :country_id
  property :zipcode
  property :phone

  extend ActiveModel::ModelValidations
  copy_validations_from Address

end
```

**Контроллер:**

```
class Users::ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :create_form, only: [:update, :edit]

  def edit
  end

  def update
    form = AddressForm.new(address_type)
    if form.validate(params_type)
      form.save
      redirect_to edit_profile_path
    else
      render :edit, notice: form.errors.full_messages
    end
  end

  def address_type
    return Address.find(@user.billing_address) if params[:billing]
    return Address.find(@user.shipping_address) if params[:shipping]
  end

  def params_type
    return params[:billing] if params[:billing]
    return params[:shipping] if params[:shipping]
  end

private
  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end

  def profile_params
    params.require(:user).
        permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

  def create_form
    @address_form = AddressPresenter.new(@user)
  end
end
```

**Presenters**

```
class AddressPresenter
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_reader :billing_form, :shipping_form

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
    @billing_form = AddressForm.new(address('billing'))
    @shipping_form = AddressForm.new(address('shipping'))
  end

  private
  def address(type)
    address_id = eval("@user.#{type}_address_id")
    address_id ? Address.find(address_id) : Address.new
  end
end
```

**View**

```
.row
  .col-md-6
    = form_for @address_form.billing_form, as: :billing, url: {action: 'update'} do |f|
      %h3= t('checkout.billing_address')
      %hr.style3
      = render 'static/error_messages', target: @address_form.billing_form
      = render 'address/form', f: f
      =  f.submit t('page.save_button'), class: 'btn btn-primary'

  .col-md-6
    = form_for @address_form.shipping_form, as: :shipping, url: {action: 'update'} do |f|
      %h3= t('checkout.billing_address')
      %hr.style3
      = render 'static/error_messages', target: @address_form.shipping_form
      = render 'address/form', f: f
      =  f.submit t('page.save_button'), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

## Update

Не пойму в чем проблема, но если сделать все строго по докам, убрать `presenters` и для одной формы то все работает - и валидация и изменение формы.

**Изменненный код контроллера:**

```
class Users::ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user

  def billing_address
    @user.billing_address || Address.new
  end

  def edit
    # сюда приходят предзаполненные данные
    @billing_address ||= AddressForm.new(billing_address) 
  end

  def update
    form = AddressForm.new(billing_address)
      if form.validate(params[:billing])
        form.save
        redirect_to action: :edit
      else
        render :edit
      end
  end

  private
  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

**View**

```
= form_for @billing_address, as: :billing, url: {action: 'update'} do |f|
      %h3= t('checkout.billing_address')
      %hr.style3
      = render 'static/error_messages', target: @billing_address
      = render 'address/form', f: f
      =  f.submit t('page.save_button'), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Comment: Ну правильно, в новом презентере нет геттеров для получения форм. Либо добавить `attr_reader :billing_form, :shipping_form`, либо удалить конструктор и класс унаследовать от `Struct.new(:billing_form, :shipping_form)`.

Comment: @anoam Спасибо! Если можно еще один момент пожалуйста подскажите - после того как я добавл геттеры в презентер форма рендерится, но при изменении предзаполненных полей - данные не перезаписываются. Дебаг показал, что в методе `update` в форму `form = choose_form` записываются старые данные. Хотя в `params` приходят новые [скрин дебага](http://joxi.net/Dr86k0DIkR4d32)

Comment: исправил свой ответ. Так должно сетить. И ещё, я внимательнее сейчас посмотрел полный код контролера - советую вынести работу с адресами в отдельный. А то уж очень много всего контроллер умеет.

Comment: @anoam к сожалению не сетит. Не подскажите в каком напрвлении стоит искать проблему? Возможно что-то с презентором не так?

Comment: @anoam На сколько я понимаю из дебага - проблема не в валидации а в том, что в методе `update` в `form` приходит старые данные (предзаполненнные)

Comment: @anoam в presenter каждый раз приходит предзаполненная форма. Отсюда и проблема с обновлением. Правда как пофиксить пока так и не разобрался.

Comment: она и должна приходить заполненной. Всё-таки обновляем данные. Нужно смотреть как работает `reform`. Я им никогда не пользовался. Скорее всего, просто не разобрался как сетить правильно.

Comment: @anoam дело не в том что она приходит заполненной. А в том, что приходят всегда предзаполненные данные ( то есть старые), а то что обновленные данные в form не заходят

Comment: Я про то и говорю. Форма собирается на основе инстанса `Address`. Бегло прочитав ридми `reform`'а я подумал что `validate` должен сетить новые данные. Видимо, ошибся. Направление куда копать - доки реформа.

Comment: @anoam да в доках я ковыряюсь уже наверное с дня 4. Но к сожалению так и не разобрался. Вот что получилось сделать по докам `reform`[ссылка](http://joxi.ru/Dr86k0DIkRze82). Код хоть и кривой но рабочий - единственный косяк этого варианта - не выводит ошибки

Comment: `form = choose_form #сюда постоянно приходят старые данные` так сюда и должны приходить старые данные. Новые сетятся здесь: `form.validate(address_params)`

Comment: Увидел косяк. Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Здесь они не сетятся на сколько я понял по докам а валидируются.

Comment: По-моему, при валидации они должны сетиться. Другого способа сетить я так и не нашёл. Возможно, конечно, сработает что-то типа `form.attributes = address_params`, но сначала надо проверить догадку с мемоизацией.

Comment: @anoam Ваш последний вариант тоже к сожалению не сетит новые данные. Я обновил код - сделал все строго по докам и для одной формы. Работает как нужно. Но увы не получается увязать 2 формы: `shipping_address` и `billing_address`. Не подскажите как можно нормально, не дублируя код оформить работу двух форм отталкиваясь от обновленного кода?

Comment: Раз такой вариант работает - новые параметры действительно сетятся через `validate` (sic.). Если так работает для одной формы - будет работать и для `N`. Просто где-то косяк. Дебаг в помощь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43868/discussion-between-alexandr-dmitrenko-and-anoam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто.
Форма(ы), на самом деле, сохраняют свои значения. Проблема в том, что при рендеринге используются **ДРУГИЕ** форм-обжекты.
В экшене `update` билдится свой форм-обжект:

> ```
> form = AddressForm.new(address_type)
> ```

Но при рендеринге используется форм-обжекты, которые создаются независимо, внутри презентера. Естественно, они ничего не знают про введённые пользователем данные. Вариант "в лоб" - использовать формы презентера, но это будет не совсем правильно с точки зрения архитектуры. Я рекомендую просто переписать контроллер и презентер так, чтобы они взаимодействовали с одними и теми же форм-обжектами. Например так:

**Контроллер:**

```
helper_method :presenter

def update
  form = choose_form
  # upd!!
  if form.validate(address_params)
    form.save
    redirect_to action: :edit
  else
    render action: :edit
  end
end

# ...
private

def choose_form
  billing? ? billing_form : shipping_form
end

def billing?
  params[:billing].present?
end

def billing_form
  # UPD2
  @billing_form ||=
    AddressForm
      .new(
        Address.find(@user.billing_address) #кстати, подозреваю что find здесь лишний
      )
end

def shipping_form
  # UPD2
  @shipping_form ||=
    AddressForm
      .new(
        Address.find(@user.shipping_address)
      )
end

def presenter
  @presenter ||= AddressPresenter.new(billing_form, shipping_form)
end
# upd!!
def address_params
  params.permit(billing? ? :billing : :shipping).permit! #вообще правильно пермитить только нужные параметры, но форм-обжект всё равно лишнее не пропустит.
end
```

**Презентер:**

```
def initialize(billing_form, shipping_form)
  @billing_form = billing_form
  @shipping_form = shipping_form
end
```

**Вьюха:**

```
= form_for presenter.billing_form, #...
```

Ну и формы не должны очищаться, и в них можно использовать `f.error_messages` и прочие плюшки форм-билдера.

Почему советую именно такой вариант, а не что-то типа `prensenter.shipping_form.validate...`:
1. Презентер освобождается от зависимостей. Уходит `eval`, который сам по себе smell, а тут ещё и сделан "не пришей рукав".
2. Избавляемся от `create_form` на коллбэке. Презентер создастся лениво.

И ещё, немного оффтопа:
В презентере лишний инклуд `ActiveModel::Model`. Вроде, он нигде не нужен. Да и вообще, его можно упростить до обычного `Struct`.

Comment: спасибо за пример. `Address.find` действительно оказался лишним. Сделал все как вы написали но наткнулся на другую проблему - теперь не рендерется вьюшка. Ошибка [ссылка](http://joxi.net/GrqLwOWSNvnyEA)

Comment: А можно актуальный код `AddressPresenter`'а увидеть?)

Comment: спасибо! Код добавлен.

Answer (score 2):

Это **идиома** в Rails, но её описание действительно не очень-то находится.

**Трюк опирается на то, что в `edit` и в `update` заполняются одинаковые объекты** для отрисовки одной и той же вьюхи: `edit`. Работает он со всем, что совместимо с `ActiveModel`, вероятно, с формами Reform тоже.

У вас ожидается, что:

- в экшене `edit` внутри `@address_form.billing_form` (аргумент `form_for`) форма будет пустой (или со значениями по умолчанию
- в экшене `update`, **в случае ошибки**, внутри `@address_form.billing_form` форма будет заполнена тем, что пришло от пользователя (даже если сохранение закончилось ошибками)

Последнее правило в вашем коде не выполняется: форма с ошибками есть только в локальном `form` в контроллере. Вам необходимо сделать так, чтобы после провалившегося `update` в `@address_form.billing_form` лежало то, что у вас сейчас в `form`.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам необходимо вывести сообщения об ошибках под каждым полем из формы, вам не обязательно для этого задействовать специализированный гем. Такая возможность предусмотрена штатными средствами Ruby on Rails. Для этого в представлении, при выводе формы нужно обратиться к методу `errors` текущей модели и выбрать среди ошибок те, которые относятся к текущем полю

```
= f.text_field :slug, class: 'form-control'
- if f.object.errors[:slug]
  .field_error
    - f.object.errors[:slug].each do |msg|
      span= msg
```

Если вынести участок обработки в отдельный partition

```
- if object.errors[field]
  .field_error
    - object.errors[field].each do |msg|
      span= msg
```

Подключать обработку ошибок можно одной строкой

```
= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
= render 'admin/shared/field_errors', object: f.object, field: :name

= f.text_field :slug, class: 'form-control'
= render 'admin/shared/field_errors', object: f.object, field: :slug
```