# Как получить сообщение об ошибке валидации

Tags: ruby-on-rails, валидация

Провожу валидацию связанной модели, первая:

```
class Bike < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :stata_fuels, dependent: :destroy  
end
```

и связанная

```
class StataFuel < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :bike

validates   :odo_delta, presence: { message: "введите пробег между заправками" }
validates   :refueling, presence: { message: "введите кол-во заправленного топлива" }
validates   :price_fuel, presence: { message: "введите сумму оплаты за топливо" }
end
```

При валидации модели Bike, получаю сообщения об ошибке из переменной обычным методом методом `@bike.errors`. Часть кода контроллера bikes_controller ниже:

```
  def create
    @bike = Bike.new(bike_params)
      if @bike.save
        redirect_to bikes_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
```

При валидации модели FuelStata валидация работает, т. е. при пустых полях данных запись в БД не производится, но я не могу получить в переменную сообщения об ошибке.

Ниже привожу часть контроллера stata_fuels_controller:

```
class StataFuelsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_view_stata_fuel

def new
  @bike = Bike.find(params[:bike_id])
  @stata_fuel = StataFuel.new
end

def create
  @bike = Bike.find(params[:bike_id])
  if @bike.stata_fuels.create(fuel_params)
    redirect_to new_bike_stata_fuel_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

и сама вьюха:

```
<h2> Fuel statistics page </h2>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <%= @bike.stata_fuels.errors %>
  <%= render 'form_fuel_create', stata_fuel: @stata_fuel %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', bikes_path %>
```

на строку с @bike.stata_fuels.errors Рельсы выдают ошибку undefined method `stata_fuel' for #.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в переменную получить сообщения об ошибках, чтобы потом их вывести в сообщении? Возможно есть нюансы сообщений об ошибках для связанных объектов?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Rails gem Reform отображение ошибок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553653/rails-gem-reform-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cначало в контролере:

```
@stata = @bike.stata_fuels.create(fuel_params)
```

Потов во вьюхе:

```
<%= @stata.errors %>
```

Comment: Проблема решена, всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку `stata_fuels` это набор (коллекция), а не собственно предмет, то он не должет отдавать список ошибок.

Чтобы проверить новые вхождения зависимого (has_many) набора в предмет, нужно выставить ему свойство `validate` в `true`:

```
class Bike
   has_many :stata_fuels, dependent: :destroy, validate: true
end
```

и проверять уже сам предмет:

```
@bike.valid?
@bike.errors
```

если вы хотите проверять не только новые, а все зависимые записи, то используйте вместо свойства `validate`, директиву `validates_associated` в модели.

```
class Bike
   has_many :stata_fuels, dependent: :destroy

   validates_associated :stata_fuels
end
```

Comment: Выполнил указанное выше, все равно не удается получить сообщение об ошибке валидации. на @bike.errors выдает пустой хеш. Пробовал через rails console - результат следующий: 
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0xb8a0290 @base=#<Bike id: 1, name: "Viper VXR 250", user_name: "Yar", year: 2014, color: "black", created_at: "2016-10-04 20:31:26", updated_at: "2016-10-04 20:31:26">, @messages={}, @details={}>

Comment: а если ввести еще одну переменную:                                   .@stata_fuel_err = StataFuel.new(fuel_params)
    @stata_fuel_err.valid?                                                                                то во вьюхе <%= @stata_fuel_err.errors.messages %><br/> сообщения валидации получаю! {:bike=>["must exist"], :odo_delta=>["введите пробег между заправками"], :refueling=>["введите кол-во заправленного топлива"] ...

Comment: @Yar-ua значит посто вы чтото не то в контроллере делаете, если вам надо дополнительно ещё одну операцию добавлять.... проверяйте

Comment: @Yar-ua и потом, какие вы варианты пробовали, оба?

Comment: Скрылевъ, да .пробовал оба варианта. При проверке bike.valid? и bike.errors в контроллере и при выводе во вьюху выводило пустой массив. Объект bike сам по себе ошибок валидации не получал т. к. подель bike валидацию прошла без ошибок. А ошибки коллекции по bike.errors не выводились.

Comment: @Yar-ua чудеса в решете, у меня такая модель работала...